# How to do typecasting without loosing a comma?

Tags: abap

**Task:**  I have `data col(30) TYPE c VALUE '-1111,45'.` and I need to check if this value is negative, if negative - do typecasting. But on the output I get 5 though I have to get 1111,45 without a minus and again do typecasting to the previous type (с).

```
REPORT Z_CAST.

data col(30) TYPE c VALUE '-1111,45'. 
data numc type n.

numc = col.

  if numc < 0.
    numc = -1 * numc.
  endif.

col = numc.

WRITE col.  "Output: 5
```

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve, but there are several problems: For numc the default length is 1, so you have to define the length as well: numc TYPE n LENGTH x. On the other hand TYPE n is basically a character type, but can contain numbers only (0-9), which means, when you assign the value from col to numc, you loose the negative sign and decimal coma as well. One solution could be to define numc as TYPE p DECIMALS 2. However before you assigne the value from col to numc, you have to replace the decial coma with dot (ABAP uses decimal dot internally).

Comment: On the other hand, if you just want to check, whether the value of col is negative, you can use IF col(1) EQ '-' (assuming the value is left justified)

Comment: @ JozsefSzikszai  if col+0(1) EQ '-'.  WRITE col+1. endif.  // Output 1111,45. But would it be correct - if I have list of some elements (positive\negative) and I must to find negative and do it positive, so this solution will be good, or I will  lose something at the same time, or overflow memory, or smth else???

Comment: It's hard to tell how to do this without knowing **to what type** casting is to be done

Comment: @ Suncatcher I need to get in the same type - c but I solve this problem (my comment above)

Comment: Suggest to change the title of your question. It is misleading. Your aim is actually not casting something to a different type, but doing a numeric operation with character fields.

Comment: @ Florian I do not think that it is misleading, moreover, my post was edited by Suncatcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
REPORT Z_CAST.

data col(30) TYPE c VALUE '-1111,45'.

if col+0(1) EQ '-'.

  WRITE col+1. "1111,45

endif.
```

Comment: Is this an answer?

Comment: Yes, it is. Mykola apparently solved his/her own question, which is highly appreciated. And posted the answer, which is even more appreciated. :-)

Comment: @ desertnaut yet, this is the answer!

Comment: @ Florian  ... Mykola apparently solved his/her own ... - I'm male so - ...his own... )))

Answer (score 1):

This is the minimum character processing way to do this:

```
col = replace( val  = col
               sub  = '-'
               with = ' ' ).
```

You don't have to find the `-` first to replace it.

Comment: @ Florian so what's the best way to use it - is your solution or mine?

Answer (score 0):

And this is the *clean* numeric way that ABAPers will usually choose:

```
DATA n TYPE p LENGTH 12 DECIMALS 2.
n = col.
n = abs( n ).
```

Note that this does **not** work with your example `'-1111,45'` though: ABAP expects a point `.` as decimal separator, but your number uses a localized format with comma `,`, so you would have to normalize the number first.

Comment: @ Florian to replace "." to ",'  - DATA: xstring(16) TYPE c.   MOVE col TO xstring.  REPLACE '.' WITH ',' INTO xstring. - can i do like that ?

Comment: Yes. Or again, simply `col = replace( val  = col sub  = ',' with = '.' )`. Although I am convinced there are some real numeric parsers out there. They're only hard to find...

Comment: @ Florian numeric parsers - can you give an example?